# Correlation and non-normal distributions

Tags: correlation, monte-carlo, normality-assumption

I have to work with bimodal and normal distributions. Starting from a set of given bimodal distribution I have to draw a set of random vectors. Some of these random vectors must have given correlation coefficients. I thought to draw a vector $x_1$ of random values from one of the bimodal distributions, and then mix with some gaussian noise $\epsilon$, in order to get a new vector $x_2$ correlated with the first. But I need to know a priori the correlation coefficient. Moreover I think I can't use pearson's correlation since mean and variance doesn't make sense for a bimodal distribution.

Any advices?

Comment: Means and variances have a formal definition for any distribution.  The Cauchy is a distribution where they don't exist because the integrals defining them are infinite.  But bimodal and many nonnormal distributions can have finite means and variances. As long as you have finite means variances and covariances the Pearson correlation is defined.  Sometimes the interpretation of these parameters is difficult for non-normal distributions but they are very natural for normal distributions.  The variance can always be helpful in terms of the information it gives in the Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: When you say "bimodal" do you mean the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like this problem can be solved with Ruscio & Kaczetow's algorithm for generating correlated non-normal variables.  It's flexible enough to work for bimodal distributions.  Their article includes R code.

Reference:

Ruscio, J., & Kaczetow, W. (2008). Simulating multivariate nonnormal data using an iterative algorithm. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 43, 355–381. doi:10.1080/00273170802285693

Comment: Thanks for this information, Anthony.  Since your reference is behind a paywall and therefore not generally accessible, and the `R` software does not seem to be available either, would it be possible to give a quick summary of the idea behind the algorithm and how it works?

Comment: It's an iterative algorithm. I'll summarize the bivariate case, but it can work with multivariate problems, too:Uncorrelated Xo and Yo are generated with any shapes (e.g. bimodal).  Then, X1 and Y1 are generated as bivariate normal with an intermediate correlation.  X1 and Y1 are replaced by X0 and Y0 in a rank-preserving fashion.

Comment: ...Adjust the intermediate correlation to be higher or lower depending on whether the r(X1,Y1) is too low or too high.  Repeat. Code can be found here:http://www.tcnj.edu/~ruscio/taxometrics.html

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, I'll certainly take a look at the paper