# How to rearrange 2D data to get given correlation?

Tags: r, correlation

I have the following simple dataset with two continuous variables; i.e.:

```
d = data.frame(x=runif(100,0,100),y = runif(100,0,100))
plot(d$x,d$y)
abline(lm(y~x,d), col="red")
cor(d$x,d$y) # = 0.2135273
```

[image: Base distribution]

I need to rearrange the data in the way to have correlation between variables to be ~0.6. I need to keep means and other descriptive statistics (sd,min,max,etc.) of both variables constant.

I know it is possible to make almost any correlation with the given data i.e.:

```
d2 = with(d,data.frame(x=sort(x),y=sort(y)))
plot(d2$x,d2$y)
abline(lm(y~x,d2), col="red")
cor(d2$x,d2$y) # i.e. 0.9965585
```

[image]

If I try to use `sample` function for this task:

```
cor.results = c()
for(i in 1:1000){
    set.seed(i)
    d3 = with(d,data.frame(x=sample(x),y=sample(y)))
    cor.results =  c(cor.results,cor(d3$x,d3$y))
}
```

I get quite wide range of correlations:

```
> summary(cor.results)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-0.281600 -0.038330 -0.002498 -0.001506  0.034380  0.288800
```

but this range depends on number of rows in data frame and decreasing with increase of size.

```
> d = data.frame(x=runif(1000,0,100),y = runif(1000,0,100))
> cor.results = c()
> for(i in 1:1000){
+ set.seed(i)
+ d3 = with(d,data.frame(x=sample(x),y=sample(y)))
+ cor.results =  c(cor.results,cor(d3$x,d3$y))
+ }
> summary(cor.results)
      Min.    1st Qu.     Median       Mean    3rd Qu.       Max. 
-0.1030000 -0.0231300 -0.0005248 -0.0005547  0.0207000  0.1095000
```

**My question is:**

How to rearrange such dataset to get given correlation (i.e. 0.7)?
(It will be also good if method will remove dependence on dataset size)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to rearrange the data that is based on generating additional random numbers.

We draw samples from a bivariate normal distribution with specified correlation. Next, we compute the ranks of the $x$ and $y$ values we obtain. These ranks are used to order the original values. For this approach, we have top sort both the original $x$ and $y$ values.

First, we create the actual data set (like in your example).

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x = runif(100, 0, 100), y = runif(100, 0, 100))

cor(d$x, d$y)
# [1] 0.01703215
```

Now, we specify a correlation matrix.

```
corr <- 0.7  # target correlation
corr_mat <- matrix(corr, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
diag(corr_mat) <- 1
corr_mat
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  1.0  0.7
# [2,]  0.7  1.0
```

We generate random data following a bivariate normal distribution with $\mu = 0$, $\sigma = 1$ (for both variables) and the specified correlation. In R, this can be done with the `mvrnorm` function from the `MASS` package. We use `empirical = TRUE` to indicate that the correlation is the empirical correlation (not the population correlation).

```
library(MASS)
mvdat <- mvrnorm(n = nrow(d), mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = corr_mat, empirical = TRUE)

cor(mvdat)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]  1.0  0.7
# [2,]  0.7  1.0
```

The random data perfectly matches the specified correlation.

Next, we compute the ranks of the random data.

```
rx <- rank(mvdat[ , 1], ties.method = "first")
ry <- rank(mvdat[ , 2], ties.method = "first")
```

To use the ranks for the original data in `d`, we have to sort the original data.

```
dx_sorted <- sort(d$x)
dy_sorted <- sort(d$y)
```

Now, we can use the ranks to specify the order of the sorted data.

```
cor(dx_sorted[rx], dy_sorted[ry])
# [1] 0.6868986
```

The obtained correlation does not perfectly match the specified one, but the difference is relatively small.

Here, `dx_sorted[rx]` and `dy_sorted[ry]` are resampled versions of the original data in `d`.

Comment: +1 That is quite cool.  The steps are 1) generate normal data with the right Pearson correlation, 2) make the original data and the generated data match rank correlations exactly, 3) original data have roughly the same Pearson correlation now.  Why does this work?  Is there an analytical result saying that it does?  Bounding inequalities keeping the various correlation measures close to one another for well-behaved distributions or something?

Comment: @Bill I cannot explain the approach analytically. It is just an idea that came to my mind. However, you summarized the steps in a nice way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To generate two uniform distributions with a specified correlation, the Ruscio & Kaczetow (2008) algorithm will work. They provide [R code](http://www.tcnj.edu/~ruscio/taxometrics.html#NonnormalData).  You can then transform with a simple linear function to get your target min, max, mean, and SD.

**Ruscio & Kaczetow Algorithm**

I'll summarize the bivariate case, but it can also work with multivariate problems.  Uncorrelated $X_o$ and $Y_o$ are generated with any shape (e.g., uniform). Then, $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are generated as bivariate normal with an intermediate correlation. $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are replaced by $X_0$ and $Y_0$ in a rank-preserving fashion. Adjust the intermediate correlation to be higher or lower depending on whether the r($X_1,Y_1$) is too low or too high. $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are generated as bivariate normal with the *new* intermediate correlation.  Repeat.

Notice that this is very similar to @Sven Hohenstein's solution, except that it's iterative, so the intermediate correlation will get closer and closer to the target correlation until they are indistinguishable.  Also, note that this algorithm can be used to generate a large population (e.g., N=1 million) from which to draw smaller samples - that is useful if you need to have sampling error.

For a related post: [Correlation and non-normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38088/correlation-and-non-normal-distributions)

**Preserving Descriptive Statistics**

There is no guarantee that the algorithm will produce the exact same descriptives.  However, because a uniform distribution's mean and SD are determined by its min and max, you can simply adjust the min and max to fix everything.

Let $X_g$ and $Y_g$ be your generated variables from the last iteration of the Ruscio & Kaczetow algorithm, $X_f$ and $Y_f$ be your final variables that you hope to have (with target descriptives), and $X$ and $Y$ be your the original variables in your dataset.

Calculate  $X_f=(X_g - min(X))*(max(X)-min(x))/(max(X_g)-min(X_g))$

Do the same for $Y_f$

**Reference:**

Ruscio, J., & Kaczetow, W. (2008). Simulating multivariate nonnormal data using an iterative algorithm. Multivariate Behavioral Research, 43, 355–381. doi:10.1080/00273170802285693

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that when you say "resample" you mean "simulate," which is more general.  The following is the most concise way I know to simulate normal, bivariate data with a specified correlation.  Substitute your own desired values for r and n.

```
r = .6
n = 1000
x = rnorm(n) 
z = rnorm(n) 
y = (r/(1-r^2)^.5)*x + z

cor(x,y)
plot(x,y)
abline(lm(y~x), col="red")
```

Comment: No I really mean "resample". I need to keep means and other descriptive statistics (sd,min,max) of both variables constant. Updated the question.